# Flutter Print To Zebra Thermal Printer -Bluetooth

Tags: flutter

has anyone tried to print to zebra bluetooth printer in Flutter
usually when we did it in native we send ZPL is there a way to send it in flutter
i have searched pub.dev but they have only for TCP/Ip printers
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom is searching for an a answer

just use this lib : https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_utils
and just send zpl string and it will print like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Haven't printed on Zebra devices but I have on other ESC/POS bluetooth thermal printers. As far as I know Zebra devices accept ESC/POS commands.

There are several packages available. That being said all of the ones I tried had either limited functionality or had a fair amount of bugs.

1) https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_basic . This is the one I opted for, didn't want to reinvent the wheel but at the same time some things are just better when you do it yourself (requires knowledge about ESC/POS commands for your use-case).

2) https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_bluetooth . This package is made by the same people as #1, comes with a good amount of ESC/POS commands available, has some bugs.

3) https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer . Tried this one briefly, it did work but overall had more bugs than #2 and lacks support for iOS.

Lastly, to prove I'm not speaking from the top of my head heh, here are my results:
[image: example bt thermal printed image]

Comment: Unfortunately my code isn't mine hah, company I work for owns the software so can't share it. Besides it would most probably be too complicated for regular use: 1) We had to make unicode support for devices that have only a handful of 256 char codepages 2) we had to support 10 different fonts and styles 3) image / logo processing (scaling, dithering)... Anyhow if you are new to the field I suggest starting with package #2 (fixed the link in my original answer), it has a pretty good example  [here](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_bluetooth/blob/master/example/blue/lib/main.dart).